# String Operation on list

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a list of integers say

> var items = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

I would like to cast them to list of strings. The reason is i need the set to be appear like

> {<- 1 -> , <-2-> ,<-3-> ,<-4-> }

Normally i create another list like

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
 foreach (int i in items) 
 {  
   list.Add("<-" + i + "->"); 
 }
```

Is there any shortcut to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ and more specifically a combination of the [`.Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) and [`.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension methods:

```
var items = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<string> list = items.Select(i => string.Format("<-{0}->", i)).ToList();
```

The `.Select()` extension method projects each integer element to the corresponding string representation and the `.ToList()` extension method casts the result to a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var lst = items.ToList().ConvertAll(x=>x.ToString()).Select(x=>"<-"+ x+"->");
```